# cloudflared installed on Compute Engine (Debian GNU/Linux) but cloudflared command is not found via Cloud Shell

Tags: linux, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, tunnel

I have to install Argo Tunnel on my server, VM on Compute Engine (Image Debian, Debian GNU/Linux, 10 (buster), amd64 built on 20200902, supports Shielded VM features), but cannot pass the cloudflared installation step.
I followed the instructions on  the developers portal:https://developers.cloudflare.com/argo-tunnel/downloads
And downloaded amd64 / x86-64 package for Linux,

I also used this code and installed cloudflared on my VM

```
    git clone 
    https://github.com/cloudflare/cloudflared.git
    cd cloudflared/
    go clean
    go get 
    github.com/cloudflare/cloudflared/cmd/cloudflared
    make cloudflared
```

I see the directory, but I cannot check the version to verify if I install everything properly ([documentation](https://developers.cloudflare.com/argo-tunnel/quickstart)).

```
    changerz_critical@cloudshell:~/cloudflared (global- 
    road-289110)$ cloudflared --version
    -bash: cloudflared: command not found
```

I honestly read through all available docs and could not find anything that could help to solve this issue.

Would be very thankful for any help.

[image]

Comment: **1.** Why don't you use `.deb` package available at [downloads](https://developers.cloudflare.com/argo-tunnel/downloads) page? You can easily install it with `sudo dpkg --install cloudflared-stable-linux-amd64.deb`. **2.** Also, you can try to follow [instructions](https://github.com/cloudflare/cloudflared) and run `go install github.com/cloudflare/cloudflared/cmd/cloudflared`.

Comment: Hi, go install is not working I used `git clone https://github.com/cloudflare/cloudflared.git
cd cloudflared/
go clean
go get github.com/cloudflare/cloudflared/cmd/cloudflared
make cloudflared`

Comment: Okay, how about preconfigured package `.deb` for Debian?

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked perfect for me. I have one question. I don't know why but  when I am trying to establish connection with localhost it gives me `Cannot determine default configuration path. No file [config.yml config.yaml] in [~/.cloudflared ~/.cloudflare-warp ~/cloudflare-warp /etc/cloudflared /usr/local/etc/cloudflare` and `Error getting origin cert: Client didn't specify origincert path when running from terminal`. Do you know probably why is that happening? Thank you very much!
d]

Answer (score 1):

**To install** `cloudflared` **on your VM instance** please follow steps below:

1. Create VM instance:

```
$ gcloud beta compute instances create instance-1 --zone=europe-west3-a --machine-type=e2-medium --image=debian-10-buster-v20200910 --image-project=debian-cloud
```

2. Connect to VM instance via SSH:

```
$ gcloud compute ssh instance-1
```

3. Download and install `cloudflared` by using `.deb` package:

```
instance-1:~$ wget https://bin.equinox.io/c/VdrWdbjqyF/cloudflared-stable-linux-amd64.deb
instance-1:~$ sudo dpkg --install cloudflared-stable-linux-amd64.deb
```

4. Check the version:

```
instance-1:~$ cloudflared --version
cloudflared version 2020.9.0 (built 2020-09-14-2204 UTC)
```

5. Follow the [instructions](https://developers.cloudflare.com/argo-tunnel/quickstart#step-3-login-to-your-cloudflare-account):

```
instance-1:~$ Please open the following URL and log in with your Cloudflare account:

https://dash.cloudflare.com/argotunnel?callback=https%3A%2F%2Flogin.argotunnel.com%2Fkob9m8T0PaRAFrkYjXjAI4vH1X4sqQ6IRtd8-D_THmYMaAM%3D

Leave cloudflared running to download the cert automatically.
```

Unfortunately, I don't have a domain to check the full setup. For further instructions I'd recommend you to post a new question at [Cloudflare community](https://community.cloudflare.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Solved with

```
git clone https://github.com/cloudflare/cloudflared.git cd cloudflared/ go clean go get github.com/cloudflare/cloudflared/cmd/cloudflared make cloudflared
```